# Clicking on an item shall highlight related data using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to highlight related data when clicking on an item in a list or a table. As an example of what I try to achieve I will use the code below. It's a list of parents and children. In this case I have used an id-attribute to identify the person and a data-* attribute to identify parents or children to the current person.

```
  <ul>
    <li id="Bill" data-children="John Anne">Bill, father</li>
    <li id="John" data-parents="Bill">John, son</li>
    <li id="Anne" data-parents="Bill">Anne, daughter</li>
    <li id="Jane" data-children="Lisa">Jane, mother</li>
    <li id="Jack" data-children="Lisa">Jack, father</li>
    <li id="Lisa" data-parents="Jane Jack">Lisa, daughter</li>
  </ul>
```

When clicking on any of the persons the related persons (parents or children) shall be highlighted. If I click on a parent, the children will be highlighted and vice versa. The selected person will also be highlighted. Here's a screenshot of two situations:
[image]

I use the following CSS classes for highlighting the data:

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.selected { color: #F88; }
```

I have made the following jQuery code, but it's very static and only works when clicking on Bill or Lisa:

```
$("#Bill").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
  $(this).addClass("selected bold");
  $("#John,#Anne").addClass("bold");
});
$("#Lisa").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
  $(this).addClass("selected bold");
  $("#Jane,#Jack").addClass("bold");
})
```

I really would like to be able the jQuery code to dynamically highlight the related parents/children. Conceptually like this:

```
$("<any person>").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
  $(this).addClass("selected bold");
  if (<selected person is a parent>) {
    $(<all persons that has data-parents==this.id>).addClass("bold");
  }
  etc...
})
```

Is this possible? Feel free to rearrange the HTML. Perhaps I can use class instead of data-* attributes?...

Comment: What if there's more than two levels, eg also grandparents, would they need to be highlighted also?

Answer (score 1):

To genericse this you can firstly add the event handler to all the `li` elements within the `ul`.

Then you can get the `id` attributes of the relatives by splitting the `data-children` or `data-parents` to an array, looping through it, and adding the `bold` class to elements which match that `id`, something like this:

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
  $(this).addClass("selected bold")
  
  var relatives = $(this).data('parents') || $(this).data('children') || '';
  relatives.split(' ').forEach(id => $('#' + id).addClass('bold'));
});
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.selected {  color: #F88; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="Bill" data-children="John Anne">Bill, father</li>
  <li id="John" data-parents="Bill">John, son</li>
  <li id="Anne" data-parents="Bill">Anne, daughter</li>
  <li id="Jane" data-children="Lisa">Jane, mother</li>
  <li id="Jack" data-children="Lisa">Jack, father</li>
  <li id="Lisa" data-parents="Jane Jack">Lisa, daughter</li>
</ul>
```

One thing to note is that this logic assumes that the `li` has either `data-children` *or* `data-parents`, but *not both*, and that there is only one level of `li` elements. If either of those are not true then you would need to amend the logic slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your dynamic solution:

```
        $("li").click(function() {
          $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          $(document).find('[data-parents="'+id+'"]').addClass("bold");
          $(document).find('[data-children="'+id+'"]').addClass("bold");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work for `data-parents="Jane Jack"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I just realize that. I tried with all li clicked, as I did not get any upvote or comment I checked with all.
Btw, Rory, what is your email id ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Demonstrated in the following fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/kf8mfa5y/2/

I added a common class to your html to target the click event to.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="Bill" class="people" data-children="John Anne">Bill, father</li>
  <li id="John" class="people" data-parents="Bill">John, son</li>
  <li id="Anne" class="people" data-parents="Bill">Anne, daughter</li>
  <li id="Jane" class="people" data-children="Lisa">Jane, mother</li>
  <li id="Jack" class="people" data-children="Lisa">Jack, father</li>
  <li id="Lisa" class="people" data-parents="Jane Jack">Lisa, daughter</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
 $(function() {
    $(".people").click(function() {
       $(".people").removeClass("selected bold");
       $("#" + this.id).addClass("selected bold");
       var parents = $("#" + this.id).attr('data-parents');
       var children = $("#" + this.id).attr('data-children');
       if (!(parents == null)) {
          var parentarr = parents.split(" ");
          $.each(parentarr, function(key, value) {
              $("#" + value).addClass("bold");
          });
       };
       if (!(children == null)) {
          var childrenarr = children.split(" ");
          $.each(childrenarr, function(key, value) {
              $("#" + value).addClass("bold");
          });
       };
    });
 });
```

CSS

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.selected { color: #F88; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("ul li").each(function(){
  $(this).on("click", function(){
    if(typeof $(this).data('children') !="undefined"){
      $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
      $(this).addClass("selected bold");
      var childItems = $(this).data('children').split(' ');
      $(childItems).each(function(){    
        $("#"+this).addClass("bold");
      });
    }
     if(typeof $(this).data('parents') !="undefined"){
        $("li").removeClass("selected bold");
        $(this).addClass("selected bold");
        var parentItems = $(this).data('parents').split(' ');
        $(parentItems).each(function(){    
          $("#"+this).addClass("bold");
        });
    }
    });
});
```